# Change textcolors and images of Android ListView when selected

Tags: android, listview

I am struggling with this which apparently is a very simple effect but incredibly haven't found any intutitive way for doing it in Android.

I have a ListView and when i select any row only that row  text color  image need to change and remaining rows images and text-colors having same previous effect means only selected items text-color and image need to change

can some one help me please

### my_row_selector:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

### list_items:-

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:textColor="@drawable/my_row_selector"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello Wrold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class

```
  text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    text1.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                }
            });
```